# Python: 'if num > 93' brings me numbers like 94,95,996,93456

Tags: python

Today is my first Python day.

Here's the code:

```
for num, line in enumerate(fo, 1):
        if str(num) > '93971':
                fp.write(str(num) + "\t" + str(line))
fo.close()
```

Weird this is that it brings me all numbers that start with 94 or 97 or 9582, etc.

How can I get required one?

Ideally what I am trying is:

```
for num, line in enumerate(fo, 1):
            if str(num) > '93971':
                    fp.write(str(num) + "\t" + str(line))
            if str(num) < '110000':
                    break
    fo.close()
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

That's how `fo` looks:

```
text one
text 3
text none
```

This should bring me like:

```
1 text one
2 text 3
3 text none
...
```

It does, but I need to get exactly what I need, only from lines 93971 to 110000.

For example:

```
93971 text test
93972 text test3
...
110000 text test2
```

Comment: Are you looking for `num > 93971` ? the index returned by enumerate is already int

Comment: You're comparing two strings. This an *alphabetical* comparison, and not a numeric one. Is this really what you intended?

Comment: You are comparing strings not numbers, so for instance, "9" is greater than "123612398659" because "9" is greater than "1".

Comment: I did it, but not working. I made it if str(num) > 93971:, but it takes everything

Comment: Are you trying to write lines numbered 93971 through 110000?

Comment: @tdelaney, yes, exactly

Comment: @SeattleAls If that is the case, ask it that way. Read my edited answer below.

Comment: If something isn't working the way you expect, don't arbitrarily change its data type. You don't want string comparison, so you don't want strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's doing string comparison. You probably want to compare numbers. Assuming the `num` on line one is an int - and it is since it's the index returned from `enumerate` - you should do:

```
if num >= 93971 and num <= 110000:
    fp.write(str(num) + "\t" + line)  # assuming line is already a str,
                                      # no need to convert
```

And in your `fp.write` line, convert it to `str`. The `and` comparison does two comparisons which both need to be true (so within the number range you want). Adjust the `<=` vs `<` depending on whether you want the start/end numbers.

The comparison can be reduced to `if 93971 <= num <= 110000:`

Edit: corrected based on the "real" question being asked.

Comment: tried int(num), num, str(num), int(str(num)), no luck

Comment: @SeattleAls What's not working? In your question, you should explain what `fo` contains or returns.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare integers instead of converting things to strings. Here's a working example using much smaller numbers that works

```
# write a test file
with open('test.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for i in range(1,1000):
        fp.write('line {}\n'.format(i))

# now read lines 99 through 108 (random example)
with open('test.txt') as fo, open('test2.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for num, line in enumerate(fo, 1):
        if num > 108:
            break
        elif num > 99:
            fp.write(str(num) + '\t' + line)

# now print what we wrote
print(open('test2.txt').read())

When run you get

 $ python3 k.py
100 line 100
101 line 101
102 line 102
103 line 103
104 line 104
105 line 105
106 line 106
107 line 107
108 line 108
```

Comment: Can you post a runnable script then? This should work... but depends on what else is going on. Do something small like lines 15 to 30 so that we can test.

Comment: I think it's important to note the changed direction of the second comparison. With in the `<` from the original code, the loop would `break` after the first line. @tdelaney: If the answers are not working, you need to explain more about what's happening. What does "not working" mean exactly?

Comment: I got it backwards! Check the end condition first.